# Problem while replacing the scaffolding layout in Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I made a blog database and created some tables in it. I have wriTten the related models and controller files for CakePHP. Also, I have been successful in adding a test user to the blog database using Cake's scaffolding feature. So far so good.
    However, I am facing problems when getting into the Views part of Cake PHP.
    I created a "default.ctp" file and placed it into apps/views/layouts folder. Following is the file:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Cake PHP Application</title>
<?=$html->css('styles');?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <?=$content_for_layout;?>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also placed the styles.css in the app/webroot/css directory. Now, when I run this in my browser, I am getting the following screen

```
css('styles');?>

(default) 6 queries took 14 ms
Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
1   DESCRIBE `posts`        5   5   3
2   DESCRIBE `users`        5   5   3
3   DESCRIBE `tags`     3   3   3
4   DESCRIBE `posts_tags`       3   3   3
5   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `posts` AS `Post` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Post`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1       1   1   1
6   SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`name`, `Post`.`date`, `Post`.`content`, `Post`.`user_id`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`firstname`, `User`.`lastname` FROM `posts` AS `Post` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Post`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20 
    2   2   1
```

Why is it not displaying the posts as it does using the scaffolding feature. I know it will be different than scaffolding as i am using my styles. But, why is it showing nothing?? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?= ?>` are PHP short tags.  Do you have short tags enabled?  It doesn't appear so.  If you view the source of the page from your browser, you will see `<?=$html->css('styles');?>`.

To fix this, just replace:

```
<?=$html->css('styles');?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $html->css('styles'); ?>
```

Do the same with the `$content_for_layout` line.

Comment: ya...I just figured that out. However, it is still not showing up the posts and test user data.

Comment: @Adit Does that mean the above problem is fixed? Please open a new question or edit this one to specify the "not showing up" problem then.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code brother of `default.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Cake Blog Application</title>
<?php echo $html->css('styles'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep this in file and done.